# Is there a thing in discord.py similar to streamTime in discord.js?

Tags: python, discord.js, discord.py

I'm using the package `youtube_dl` for the play music command.
After a while, now I've been working on the rewind & forward commands, I have implemented a basic seek command using `ffmpeg` options, so the only thing left is just to find the position of the track being played by the bot, so that I can seek (position +- ) to go to that position of the track. The only thing I've figured out is to count the progression of the track like this.

```py
async def count_progress(self):
    try:
        if not self.on_count:
            self.on_count = True
            while self.is_playing:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.99)  
            self.queue._queue[0].progress += 1
            self.on_count = False
    except (AttributeError, IndexError):
        self.on_count = False
```

I found that discord.js has something called `streamTime`, is there anything similar in `discord.py`? if not is there any better way than just counting the progress?

**Update:** I have forgotten about this post I made but ever since I have found a really nice solution to this problem.

What I did was making a custom class to count the bytes read by the player. (Thanks to this [issue](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/issues/126) I made)

```py
class CalculableAudio(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, original, start, volume: float):
        self.played = start
        super().__init__(original, volume=volume)

    def read(self) -> bytes:
        self.played += 20 # reading 20 frames at a time (1 sec = 1000 frames)
        return super().read()
```

Then whenever I want to find the seconds played I just need to do this:

```py
seconds_played = ctx.voice_client.source.played//1000
```

Comment: Please don't tag [`discord.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) if y6our question is about [`discord.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py).

Comment: @Tyler2P Eh, it's about both.

Comment: @TylerH Although that's technically true, the OP is asking help for a `python` module whereas `discord.js` is a JavaScript module.

Comment: @Tyler2P OP wants to know if there is something in the Python module that emulates something that is in the JavaScript module. Knowledge of both is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this piece of code in player.py ( one of the modules of discord.py ) which is responsible for playing audio:

```
       while not self._end.is_set():
            # are we paused?
            if not self._resumed.is_set():
                # wait until we aren't
                self._resumed.wait()
                continue

            # are we disconnected from voice?
            if not self._connected.is_set():
                # wait until we are connected
                self._connected.wait()
                # reset our internal data
                self.loops = 0
                self._start = time.perf_counter()

            self.loops += 1
            data = self.source.read()

            if not data:
                self.stop()
                break

            play_audio(data, encode=not self.source.is_opus())
            next_time = self._start + self.DELAY * self.loops
            delay = max(0, self.DELAY + (next_time - time.perf_counter()))
            time.sleep(delay)
```

Therefore If you do :

```
loop_count = ctx.voice_client._player.loops
```

This gives the loop count which the playing thread has gone through, which can be useful for representing the time position of the audio.

```
time_position_in_second = loop_count // 50
```

I would also recommend doing a floor division of 50 to convert it into seconds, since the loop runs every 20 ms which is 50 times in a second.

Answer (score 3):

A few things right here at your disposal!

TL;DR - No, such a thing never existed in discord.py and never will.

---

- In discord.js v12 there used to be a **[StreamDispatcher](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/StreamDispatcher)** which had a **[StreamDispatcher.streamTime](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=streamTime)** property which was further removed in v13 (discord.js) and is being re-added as per **[this commit](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/commit/8c0685fa9a827bfa11e1864fcb6958f3df948c24)** on the official Discord.js repository.
- Talking about your primary issue, **Discord.py** has been *discontinued* and will not be receiving any updates from the developer from now on, and previously it **did not** have any such method to access the stream time of the client's stream ( voice / video -  not applicable to bot users) anyway. You may refer the **[documentation's VoiceClient](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voiceclient#discord.VoiceClient)** section and review for yourself that no such attribute / method existed at any point.

Although Python itself is at your service! you may declare a variable of the time it starts playing and subtract it from the time right now!

```py
# when command is first used save it to a database or as a variable simply :P starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
@client.command()
async def playtime(ctx):
    time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - starttime
    time = str(uptime).split(".")[0]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Total playtime", description=f"**time** = " + ''  + time +'')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```